# Convert from latitude, longitude to geoTIFF screen pixel x,y coordinates in Python

Tags: python, georeferencing, rasterio

I'm trying to use rasterio or pyproj to convert latitude and longitudes into the SCREEN xy coordinates of a geotiff, so that I can superimpose 2D objects on it in a raster plotting library.

Specifically: I have a geotiff that is 512x512 in epsg:3857 representing a small area of satellite imagery.

I have a known lat long that is in that expanse somewhere. If it were in dead center, the transformation I want would yield 256,256 (50%,50% of 512,512).

How to do it? I tried:

```
import rasterio as rio
latitude, longitude = 39.60378691188893, -104.9429961240613
dataset = rio.open('satellite_downloads/geotiff/home.tif', crs='epsg:3857')
pprint(dataset.crs)
pprint(dataset.transform)
py, px = dataset.index(x= longitude, y=latitude)
print('Pixel Y, X coords: {}, {}'.format(py, px))
```

But this returns

> CRS({'init': 'epsg:3857'}) Affine(0.14929107090938487, 0.0,
> -11682239.10936522,
> 0.0, -0.1492910709366697, 4808569.838743366)
>
> Pixel Y, X coords:  32209094, 782507220

How do I convert that into a value between 0 - 511 (my raster xy range)?

Comment: Have you tried swapping lat/lon to `index(x=lon, y=lat)`?

Comment: hi! yes, thank you, that was my mistake, but doesn't reproject the coords (updated ticket with that fix). Any ideas how do I convert 32209094, 782507220 into my screen pixel dimensions?

Comment: Are your coordinates also in web mercator?  If they're in WGS84 or something else then you'll need to reproject them to match the raster (or the other way around)

Comment: The coordinates are latitude and longitude. If I convert them Mercator, I get y=-11682195.3, x=4808529.7, which produces 110460491, 110460516. None of that can be right. Conceptually, I am missing the transformation from EPSG:3857 to the pixels in my raster image (512x512). I don't know how to do that transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was overthinking this, which may be why no one has posted an answer before:

We just need to calculate the x,y proportion of the image bounding box and multiply the pixel size of the satellite image to get the x,y of the image.

```
from pprint import pprint
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import rasterio as rio

def image_latlon_pxpy(latitude, longitude):
    dataset = rio.open('satellite_downloads/geotiff/home.tif', crs='epsg:3857')
    coords = transform(Proj(init='epsg:4326'), Proj(init='epsg:3857'), longitude, latitude)
    px, py = coords[0], coords[1]
    print(px,py)
    px_pc = (px - dataset.bounds.left) / (dataset.bounds.right - dataset.bounds.left)
    py_pc = (dataset.bounds.top - py) / (dataset.bounds.top - dataset.bounds.bottom)
    return (px_pc*dataset.width, py_pc*dataset.height)

pprint(image_latlon_pxpy(39.603786, -104.9429))
(256,256)
```

I assume this may be increasingly inaccurate for large satellite image tiles without spherical projection, but for small tiles it works fine.

Comment: If I do want to exclude this line `coords = transform(Proj(init='epsg:4326'), Proj(init='epsg:3857'), longitude, latitude)` and maintain the **espg:3857** how do I read the `coords` ??